There are more sublocales than subspaces.
In this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2406.12486v1 it is written:

Given a topological space $X$, there are typically more
sublocales in its frame of opens $\Omega(X)$ than subspaces in X.

Can you please explain this sentence. Thanks!
